# React native using deep link after code push sync

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, deeplink, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am working with React Native code push and deep link.
They works fine. The problem is, when I click in deep link with token, like `/tokenValidation/:token`, will open the application in first screen, so redirect route to `tokenValidation`, and request to API to validate token.

But in the same time, the `code push sync` is already finished, so the application automatically restart... and the process will do again...

Obs.: I am not using Linking or something, only direct with path params.

here is my code push script, have some problem?

sorry, I couldn't reproduce the behavior in gif...
[image]

I want to know what is the problem, and am I correctly with the problem? How to resolve that? I guess is just some config I didn't know...
Thanks.